# pygithub create pull request GithubException "not all refs are readable"

Tags: git, github, github-api, pygithub

I am using [Pygithub](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/PullRequest.html?highlight=create%20pull%20request) to trying to create a pull request.

```
# push branch
cmd = ["git", "push", "origin", "HEAD:refs/heads/my-branch"]
subprocess.run(cmd, check=True)
...
# then create PR
repo = client.get_repo(MY_GITHUB_REPO)
repo.create_pull(title=title, body=body, head=my-branch, base="master")
```

I got his Exception

```
github.GithubException.GithubException: 422 {"message": "Validation Failed", "errors": 
[{"resource": "PullRequest", "code": "custom", "message": "not all refs are readable"}], 
"documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-pull-request"}
```

I checked the branch exist on Github but I am getting this exception.
I tried to run a `git fetch origin` before the `repo.create_pull()` but the error persisted. I am not sure how to get around this.

Comment: maybe you have the same case : https://github.community/t/working-across-organizations-with-github-apps/13721

Answer (score 4):

Ensure you have enabled read access to "Contents" in your application's settings:

[image: Showing the contents access setting within the application's settings]

Or, if you are using one, within your "fine-grained" personal access token settings:

[image: Showing the contents access setting within the personal access settings]

Comment: Adding `contents: read` to permissions works for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

422 Unprocessable Entity
indicates missing_field A required field on a resource has not been set.
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#client-errors

or like this issue explains
you're pushing to a ref that we use just for the PR metadata.
That's also the reason you didn't get a permission denied area, since the PR ref is in the repo you have access to, even though the branch the PR is based on isn't.

https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/591